# Extjs Paging with additional Parameter

Tags: javascript, extjs, pagination

I'am working on a ExtJS 4.2 Project, where i want to use a Paging Toolbar to navigate through Images. 
When i open the Window, all Images are correct, but when i click on the next button to see the next Images, the result is empty. Its because the Parameter Id isn't passed to the backend System.
I saw in other Threads an option like `baseParams` but they are not in the documentation and don't work.

```
//My Store Class
Ext.define('App.store.Images', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  model: 'App.model.Images',
  autoLoad: false,
  autoSync: false,
  storeId: 'Images',
  pageSize: 8,
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/getImages',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'images',
        totalProperty: 'total'
    }
  }
});
// This code is execute when i open the Window
var imagesStore = Ext.StoreManager.get('Images');
imagesStore.on('load', buildContent);
imagesStore.load({
    params: {
        id: record.get('id'),
        start: 0,
        limit: 8
    }
});
```

Where can be additional Parameter be defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact you can define extraParams on the store proxy. You can do this just before the load method call :

```
Ext.apply(store.getProxy().extraParams, {
    'yourId': yourId
});
```

or in your proxy config :

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/getImages',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'images',
        totalProperty: 'total'
    }
    extraParams: {
        'yourId': yourId
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I only looked for the `baseParams` and `extraParams` on the `Ext.data.proxy.Proxy` Page and not on the `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax` Page